# Incorrect values with rownumber

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table Vente that contains the following columns :

```
[datecol]||[Code Article]||[Prix de vente TTC]||[Code Site]||[Code Structure]||promo
```

I am looking to extract columns from vente which promo =0 and datecol (date of sales) has the following conditions :

- datecol should be included in the 28 max dates in which promo=0

I try

```
    select t1.[datecol],t1.[Code Article],t1.[Prix de vente TTC],t1.[Code Site],t1.[Code Structure]
      from [Vente] t1
      inner join (select distinct [datecol],
      row_number() over(partition by [Code Article],[Code Site] ,[Code Structure] order by [datecol] desc) as rn
           from [Vente] t2
            where promo = 0
            and [Code Article] = t2.[Code Article]
            and [Code Structure]=t2.[Code Structure]
            and [Code Site]=t2.[Code Site]
            and ([Code Article] is not null) and ([Code Structure] is not null) and ([Prix de Revient] is not null)
          ) a
           on a.datecol=t1.datecol
            where promo = 0  and  rn <= 28
```

I also try the following query

```
select t1.[datecol],t1.[Code Article],t1.[Prix de vente TTC],t1.[Code Site],t1.[Code Structure]
      from [Vente MPX] t1
      inner join (
            select top 28 [datecol] from (select distinct [datecol]
            from [Vente MPX] t2
            where promo = 0
            and [Code Article] = t2.[Code Article]
            and [Code Structure]=t2.[Code Structure]
            and [Code Site]=t2.[Code Site]
            and ([Code Article] is not null) and ([Code Structure] is not null) and ([Prix de Revient] is not null)
            ) t 
           ) a
           on a.datecol=t1.datecol
            where promo = 0
```

I got incorrect values , how to modify it ?

Comment: Your query makes no sense. Seems like you try some kind of correlation in `a`, but this is not working as expected. And you talk about `promo=1` but you use `promo=0`. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: _"in which promo=1"_ -- `where promo = 0`? same style as in prior instances of this question. You should finally understand it yourself what you want to obtain with this query.

Comment: `and [Code Article] = t2.[Code Article]` - server gave you syntax error when you tried to link left field with `t1` table alias, you removed it and now guess whose field is it on the left part of comparison?

Comment: Your WHERE-conditions in the Dervied Table like `[Code Article] = t2.[Code Article]` are nonsense, i.e. the same as `1=1`.